# What does "newest" actually sort by?

Tags: support, search

I was attempting to search through questions I had asked to find one in particular. I figured "newest" would sort by "date posted", which is (my) logical alternative to "activity". However, looking at how [my questions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/925978/eric?tab=questions&sort=newest&page=2) were sorted, this clearly isn't the case. What does "newest" actually sort by, and how is it different from "activity"? Is there any way to sort my questions by date posted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sort order is working exactly as you expect; the date stamps that are shown do not correspond to the sort order however. They seem to always represent activity date, regardless of whether you're sorting by activity date or something else.

Comment: There is an operator for advanced specific search, for example, `[PHP] answers:0 closed:0` which can be given in search box. Is there any operator that I can append to pull up the newest questions?