# New nav appears to sort newest recommended questions in reverse

Tags: bug, status-completed, new-nav

Edit:
At the time of this edit the sorting appears to be fixed. Also, a duplicate report on MSE: [Recommended + all + newest sorts in reverse order (oldest first)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/259342/recommended-all-newest-sorts-in-reverse-order-oldest-first)

Here's my top of the list of 'newest' recommended questions:
[image: list of 'newest' questions]

And here's the end of the list at the bottom of page 2:
[image: bottom of newest questions list]

These are obviously descending by date asked.

If I look at the [top question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23999362/an-integration-test-fails-when-running-with-other-integration-tests-which-have-t) from the first screenshot, it does have a new answer in the last two hours, but that is still in no way the newest question.

I've seen [What does "newest" actually sort by?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255040/what-does-newest-actually-sort-by) which points out that newest questions aren't actually sorted by what is displayed as the activity date (although every one of these is shown with the 'asked' label, not a 'modified' or 'answered' and ["Newest" questions in the [ios] tag is showing very old questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266543/newest-questions-in-the-ios-tag-is-showing-very-old-questions) which seems to blame caching which [I suppose is possibly worth blaming](http://shouldiblamecaching.com/).

Comment: It only sorts this way if the filter is `recommended`. Any other filter sorts with newest first.

Comment: I just wanted to report the same. Since this will be my preferred view, it really gets into my way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has been fixed, and is currently in production.